# Creating untidy data for formatting purposes

Tags: r, reformatting

I sure could use some help on this atypical problem. I am helping a friend with a research study and he needs his data reformatted for the computer to ingest and present for survey of his faculty.

He needs to flip each row of the current dataframe into a single column that repeats. I could not find anything out there for this unique formatting issue despite a couple of weeks of searching.

Here is the dataframe example:
[normal data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9iez4.png)

Here is the final product my friend needs:
[untidy data product](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9rlNI.png)

Thanks in advance for any help you can offer.

Sample dataframe:

```
narratives <- c("Jenny did a great ...", "John was proficient ...", "Davis was lazy and ...")
qual_ex <- data.frame(narratives)
qual_ex$know <- paste("Knowledge:", "\n", "Yes", "\n", "No")
qual_ex$skill <- paste("Skills:", "\n", "Yes", "\n", "No")
qual_ex$att <- paste("Attitude:", "\n", "Yes", "\n", "No")
```

Comment: Please use dput to show the example  Try `df2 <- data.frame(Narrative = c(t(df1)))`

Comment: Not a problem, try with the code i edited

Comment: Thanks, @akrun. That did the trick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We get the transpose (`t`) of the data.frame ('df1'),  convert the `matrix` to a `vector` with `c` (or `as.vector`), and create a `data.frame` with single column

```
df2 <- data.frame(Narrative = c(t(df1)))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun for explaining the solution. I also appreciate your rapid assist. +1 if I could give it to you.